# Stata: Dummy variable as instrument in xtivreg or xtivreg2?

Tags: binary, panel, stata

I am trying to estimate the price elasticity of electricity demand for time series data. In order to handle the endogeneity of price, I am running a panel IV regression.

Treatment groups (4) and 1 control group were randomly assigned and assign the household to a certain pricing program so treatment status should be highly correlated with the endogenous variable (log_price). However, due to random assignment, the treatment status should not be correlated with log_usage. I also include weather variables and a vector of household variables when not using fixed effects/xtivreg2. Treatment is a dummy variable for any treatment group vs. control. I have tried two regressions but both give me errors:

(1) xtivreg:

```
   xtset ID datetime
   xtivreg log_usage weather (log_price = i.treatment) household_vars
   /// Error: Matsize too small
```

--> Here I am told that my matsize is too small, although I have set it to 800. I have a very large data set so maybe this is impossible?

(2) xtivreg2

```
  xtset ID datetime
  xtivreg2 log_usage weather (log_price = i.treatment), fe
  ///Error: Factor variables not allowed
```

(3) I would actually prefer to somehow differentiate between the different treatment groups (1-4) so I created dummies for each of the groups. The control group is the omitted base group:

```
  xtset ID datetime
  xtivreg log_usage weather (log_price = i.group1 i.group2 i.group3 i.group4)
  ///Error: matsize too small
```

How do I run xtivreg or xtivreg2 with binary variables as a instrument (or instruments)? How do I differentiate between any form of treatment and control and the individual treatment groups (1-4)?

Comment: It looks like you need to increase your matrix size (e.g. `set matsize 10000`). You are asking 2-3 questions in this post, which are only tangentially related to the errors you're getting.

Comment: The maximum matsize for me (Stata 13) is 800 so I cannot set it to a larger size.

Comment: Sounds like you have the IC flavor of Stata. You are limited to 798 explanatory (right-hand side) variables.